# How do sites like tabsite automatically hook up with Facebook Developer to register new apps on the fly?

Tags: facebook

have developed some quite good basic Facebook App development experience, can hook apps up to databases, have different info installed and displayed on different tabs no probs. However, everything Ive been doing so far to date revolves around me manually going into my developer account and setting up each apps settings individually, one at a time. Am curious to figure out how people like tabsite have created an interface that captures users input data and displays on tabs (that part i understand) but also it registers new apps each time on the fly (this part am curious about how its done), allowing them to add individual app logos, tabnames etc without the user ever having to go anywhere near the developer set up. And how are tabsite getting data back from the developer such as app_id or app_secret??
Any insight much appreciated.
Regards Tony

Answer (score 0):

As I recall there isn't a way to register an app using the API. They probably just use only one app, and then check the signed_request variable to get the Facebook Page ID, which they then link together with the data in the database.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Hi Leo, all different app id's and also allow to select and upload individual app icons

Answer (score 0):

You're allowed 2 tabs on a single page on their free account. But you can only add an app once. This implies they've either created a number of apps that are exactly the same(11 would be my guess as that's how many tabs their best plan offers) There used to be a way to do it using one of the old SDKS but as far as I was aware it was deprecated and is no longer available.

The fact that you say you can customise the tab image though, does imply that they're creating new apps, as far as I am aware you can only customise the image within the app settings in the developer app.

After a bit of investigation, this post may have more info

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6264080/create-a-facebook-application-programmatically